# C#.net to Java- Encryption and decryption using AES with Password

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to reproduce the following encryption/decryption algorithm in Java, but I can't find the alternatives for multiple methods such as Rfc2898DeriveBytes() and RijndaelManaged(). How do I do this?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace CryptingTest
{   
    public static class StringCipher
    {
        // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm in bits.
        // We divide this by 8 within the code below to get the equivalent number of bytes.
        private const int Keysize = 128;

        // This constant determines the number of iterations for the password bytes generation function.
        private const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
        {
            // Salt and IV is randomly generated each time, but is preprended to encrypted cipher text
            // so that the same Salt and IV values can be used when decrypting.  
            var saltStringBytes = Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
            var ivStringBytes = Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
            var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
            {
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
                using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                                // Create the final bytes as a concatenation of the random salt bytes, the random iv bytes and the cipher bytes.
                                var cipherTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                                cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                                cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                                memoryStream.Close();
                                cryptoStream.Close();
                                return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            // Get the complete stream of bytes that represent:
            // [32 bytes of Salt] + [16 bytes of IV] + [n bytes of CipherText]
            var cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            // Get the saltbytes by extracting the first 16 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var saltStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the IV bytes by extracting the next 16 bytes from the supplied cipherText bytes.
            var ivStringBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip(Keysize / 8).Take(Keysize / 8).ToArray();
            // Get the actual cipher text bytes by removing the first 64 bytes from the cipherText string.
            var cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Skip((Keysize / 8) * 2).Take(cipherTextBytesWithSaltAndIv.Length - ((Keysize / 8) * 2)).ToArray();

            using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
            {
                var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
                using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
                    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                        {
                            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                                var decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                                memoryStream.Close();
                                cryptoStream.Close();
                                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static byte[] Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy()
        {
            var randomBytes = new byte[16]; // 16 Bytes will give us 128 bits.
            using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Fill the array with cryptographically secure random bytes.
                rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
            }
            return randomBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here's a code snippet from what I tried so far but it's still off:

```java
private static byte[] Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy()
{
    var randomBytes = new byte[16]; // 16 Bytes will give us 128 bits.
       
    SecureRandom rngCsp = new SecureRandom();
    // Fill the array with cryptographically secure random bytes.
    rngCsp.nextBytes(randomBytes);
        
    return randomBytes;
}
    
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String passPhrase) 
{
    try
    {
        var saltStringBytes = Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), saltStringBytes, 1000, 384);
        Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 16);
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 16, iv, 0, 16);

        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivSpec);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements PBKDF2, and `RijndaelManaged` with a block size of 128 bits implements AES. Both seem to be applied correctly in the Java code.

However, there are differences in determining the IV and regarding concatenation: In the C# code, the salt and IV are determined randomly and concatenated with the ciphertext at the end.
In the Java code only the salt is determined randomly, the IV is derived together with the key and the concatenation is missing.

I.e. the `encrypt()` method in the Java code could be changed for instance as follows, so that a decryption with the C# code is possible:

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

...

byte[] salt = Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();
byte[] iv = Generate128BitsOfRandomEntropy();

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 128);
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

byte[] saltIvCiphertext = ByteBuffer.allocate(salt.length + iv.length + ciphertext.length).put(salt).put(iv).put(ciphertext).array();
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(saltIvCiphertext);
```

Note that for PBKDF2, an iteration count of 1000 is generally too low.